# Google Cloud Storage solution to join 2 CSV in a bucket file based on a common column

Tags: join, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I need help/suggestions to implement the below use case.

I have 2 csv files in Google Cloud Storage bucket, I need to join these 2 files, based on one common column, and I need to save the output file back into the Google Cloud Storage bucket.

I need to implement this using any Google Cloud solution (cloud data flow with beam python), Cloud function or any other Cloud solutions, since I am new to Google cloud platform, I request all to help me on implementing this use case.

Looking forward to hearing from you

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several way to achieve this. If the result of the merge take less than 1Gb and you want only 1 output file, you can do like this

- Query external CSV files from BigQuery (federated query) and save the result in a temporary table like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE mydataset.table1
OPTIONS (
  format = 'CSV',
  uris = ['gs://mybucket/file1.csv'],
  skip_leading_rows = 1
)

CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE mydataset.table2
OPTIONS (
  format = 'CSV',
  uris = ['gs://mybucket/file2.csv'],
  skip_leading_rows = 1
)

CREATE TABLE mydataset.newtable
OPTIONS(
  expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
) AS
SELECT * 
FROM mydataset.table1 join mydataset.table2 ON ....
```

- Then, [export the temp table `mydataset.newtable` to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data)

Else, you can use the solution that I describe in [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/merge-clean-transform-your-csvs-easily-with-bigquery-3a73c0c26d57) (that I wrote)

---

**EDIT 1**

You can use this sample of workflow definition that do what you need.

```
- loadFile1:
    call: http.post
    args:
      url: https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<projectID>/jobs
      auth:
        type: OAuth2
      body:
        configuration:
          query:
            query: CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE mydataset.table1 OPTIONS (format = 'CSV', uris = ['gs://mybucket/file1.csv'], skip_leading_rows = 1)
            useLegacySql: false
- loadFile2:
    call: http.post
    args:
      url: https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<projectID>/jobs
      auth:
        type: OAuth2
      body:
        configuration:
          query:
            query: CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE mydataset.table2 OPTIONS (format = 'CSV', uris = ['gs://mybucket/file2.csv'], skip_leading_rows = 1)
            useLegacySql: false
- joinQuery:
    call: http.post
    args:
      url: https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<projectID>/jobs
      auth:
        type: OAuth2
      body:
        configuration:
          query:
            query: CREATE TABLE mydataset.newtable OPTIONS( expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) AS SELECT * ......
            useLegacySql: false
    result: queryResult
- getState:
    call: http.get
    args:
      url: ${"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<projectID>/jobs/" + queryResult.body.jobReference.jobId}
      auth:
        type: OAuth2
    result: jobState
    next: testState
- testState:
    switch:
      - condition: ${jobState.body.status.state == "DONE"}
        next: extractData
    next: waitAndGetState
- waitAndGetState:
    call: sys.sleep
    args:
      seconds: 1
    next: getState
- extractData:
    call: http.post
    args:
      url: https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<projectID>/jobs
      auth:
        type: OAuth2
      body:
        configuration:
          extract:
            destinationUri: gs://<YourBucket>/bq-extract.csv
            destinationFormat: CSV
            sourceTable:
              projectId: <projectID>
              datasetId: mydataset
              tableId: newtable
    result: extractResult
- returnOutput:
    return: ${extractResult}
```

Then, use Cloud Scheduler to call directly the [Create Workflow execution API](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/executions/rest/v1/projects.locations.workflows.executions/create) with an empty body `{}` and a OAuth2 authentication mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can’t use Bigquery, it would be helpful if you provide solution with apache beam python (cloud data flow as a runner). The preferred cloud services are cloud storage , Apache beam with data flow as runner

Comment: Why you can't use BigQuery? Google itself say that, when you can use BigQuery, it's always faster and cheaper than any other solution (Beam, Hadoop or other bigdata processor)

Comment: Thanks for your response, i can use Bigquery export data, but i need to run this on daily basis then how can i schedule Biquery export data on Daily, Do we have any option to schedule/Automate your solution...Looking forward to hear for help..Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Yes, you can run scheduled queries with BigQuery. But, because you have several request to run, I recommend you to use Google Workflows to orchestrate the different call. Then, you can use Cloud Scheduler to run a Workflow execution on daily basis. Let me know if you need more guidance on that option

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
I have file1.csv & file2.csv files in gcs bucket , then i need to join these 2 files based on one common column,and then i need to write output file back into cloud storage bucket. 
 I have to run above answered 3  queries on daily basis, please help me how can i schedule/automate these Biquery exports on Google Workflows with Cloud Scheduler.

Comment: Requesting you to help me give more info on automating your solution by using Google Workflows to orchestrate and Cloud Scheduler to run a Workflow execution on daily basis..Thanks in advance

Comment: I shared the trickiest part of the job. You can customize it as you wish. Cloud Scheduler shouldn't be an issue I think.